# Reporting Services Borderstyle Property Issue

Tags: reporting-services, border

I am using the matrix control in `RS2008`. I want to use an expression to set the Value cell (col 2, row 2) of the matrix to have either no border or a double border on the bottom. I have a `boolean` field that sets this condition for each row of the report. The expression for the bottom borderstyle is...

```
=Iif(Fields!DoubleBottom.Value=True, "Double", "None")
```

The border width is set to `3pt`. When this expression is in the Value cell, the expression seems to be evaluated backwords. When the property is `True` there is no border and when the property is `False` there is a double border. Besides the reversal problem, the double border is applied to all lines in the report. Not just the lines where the property is `True`. If I remove the expression from the Value cell and place it into the cell at (col 1, row 2), it works just fine. That is the first cell in every row has the appropriate border. Any ideas as to why the Value cell should behave this way? I am setting other conditional properties to this cell and they work fine. For example, I am setting the `Format` property (number of decimal places) and that works.

Answer (score 1):

For the issue with the double border being applied to all lines in the report, I was having this issue with a conditional border. My issue was fixed by setting the default BorderStyle property to "None".